# DropDown incremento de campo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Bom, estou com o seguinte problema.

Tenho que utilizar uma função em JavaScript ou JQuery para add novos campos para preencher e salvar no banco de dados.
Nesses campos tenho que utilizar um DropDown, mas não sei como vou buscar os dados do banco de dados. 
Utilizo telerik.

O que tenho é isso

```
$("#incremento").click(function () {

var acrescentar = '@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id_dis, new SelectList(ViewBag.Disciplina, "Id_dis", "Nome"), new { @class = "form-control" })';

$('#etapa').append(acrescentar);

});


var disciplina = from disci in Documento_Caract_BD.DocumentoCaractConnection.Model.
                        Tb_disciplinas.OrderBy(o => o.Nome).ToList()
                        select new
                        {
                            Id_dis = disci.Id_dis,
                            Nome = disci.Nome
                        }
                            into myDisciplina
                            select myDisciplina;

            ViewBag.Disciplina = disciplina.ToList();
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Poderia por favor postar o código que você está utilizando?

Comment: Criar novos campos na tela e submeter esse form para o servidor?

Comment: postei logo embaixo a dúvida

Comment: E  o código c#? como está fazendo? Voce quer pegar oc onteúdo desses drop down list e adicionar no banco de dados?

Comment: estou passando por ViewBag os dados.

Answer (score 3):

> Você não adicionou informações sobre sua estrutura, então colocarei uma resposta um pouco genérica.

Esse é mais um inevitável caso para o uso do [BeginCollectionItem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A20615%20begincollectionitem).

Primeiro você precisa instalar o [BeginCollectionIten](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) via **NuGet**.

> Install-Package BeginCollectionItem

Feito isso, primeiro cria uma `Action` para obter o novo elemento da lista (ao clicar no +), desta forma:

```
public ActionResult ObterDisciplina()
    {
       ViewBag.Disciplina = disciplina.ToList();//Adiciona o método para povoar do DropDownList aqui
        var disciplina = new Disciplina();

        return PartialView("_Disciplina", disciplina);
    }
```

Nesta Action estamos criando uma nova disciplina e retornando uma `PartialView` com a mesma. Sua `PartialView` será a mesma coisa que o código que você utilizou no `append`, em sua pergunta. Ficará assim:

```
@model Projeto.Disciplina//Altere isso para seu Model

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Disciplinas"))//O nome da sua lista aqui
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(/*A pripriedade que irá ser salva aqui e a ViewBag*/);
}
```

O nome Disciplinas desta parte `@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Disciplinas"))` deve ser o mesmo nome da virtual `public virtual ICollection<Disciplina> Disciplinas{get;set;}` em seu Model.

Em sua `View`, vamos alterar a forma de "duplicar" o campo, utilizando uma requisição `ajax` para o `controller`.

```
<script>
    $('#incremento').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ObterDisciplina", "NOMECONTROLLER")',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#etapa').append(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Nesta requisição estamos adicionando uma disciplina em seu código (realizando a requisição no `controller`).

Note que nesta parte `$('#etapa').append(data);` estamos fazendo o `append()` da `PartialView()` para o elemento com o `id="etapa"`.

Fazendo isso, ao mandar salvar via `POST` normal, o seu `Model` irá possuir uma lista de disciplinas.

Comment: não gosto dessa abordagem, apesar de já te-la utilizado, é um request para retornar uma view sem necessidade. Nos dias de hoje há melhores formas, como usar MVVM ou até mesmo usar jquery clone...

Comment: @Rod Acho que você está se equivocando. Ao utilizar qualquer um desses métodos você consegue ver facilmente, mas para enviar os dados para o `controller` você precisa de uma comunicação. Apenas utilizar o clone do jQuery não irá ter o resultado esperado.

Comment: não estou me equivocando, veja bem, o motivo de não chegar ao controller uma lista, é por motivo do model binder, o begin collection, cria um index como hidden, e os names vão sendo acrescentados guid, uma forma também de fazer é usando clone sim! basta apenas fazer um index ou fazer sequencial os names

Comment: @Rod Isso sim, mas dará no mesmo no final, não concorda?

Comment: o envio da lista sim, mas com begincollection são request no servidor, que poderiam ser evitados

Comment: Não leve por outro lado, sua resposta está correta, até dei upvote, só comentei que há outras abordagens, que não necessitaria fazer o request na partialview

Comment: @Rod Sim, eu percebi e nem por um segundo pensei que era algo "ruim" os seus comentários, pelo contrário. 
Mas não vejo problemas em questão da requisição no servidor, até pq com isso eu posso fazer validações caso necessário, o que poderia vir a ser uma "falha" se for feito no client side. Mas isso não vem ao caso dessa pergunta, apenas expandi um pouco... xD

Answer (score -2):

Bruno,

Você está confundido as coisas. O HTML helper irá ser executado no servidor, você irá trabalhar com o resultado da execução no navegador.

A Telerik possui uma API que te ajuda a fazer estas operações no lado do cliente(navegador).

Dê uma olhada, procure exemplos e não desista.

Comment: Estou procurando, mas não to conseguindo achar exemplos para me salvar. Rs

Comment: Bruno, neste caso há duas operações. A primeira será a inclusão do registro no Banco de Dados (Procure sobre "Como inserir um registro via ajax .net"), A segunda etapa é, após a  primeira ter sido feita com sucesso como incluir a informação do novo registro no DropDown. Tente fazer a primeira, depois volte e pergunte como fazer a segunda :)

Comment: Mais eu quero apenas que venha os dados que estão no campo. Preciso de mais campos, é como se fosse endereço. Tenho 1 endereço e quero add o outro, tenho aquele "+" na frente para add o outro, só que não quero limitar..